# Add javascript to the source code of a specific page from my PC

Tags: javascript, addition, client-side, inject

I have this situation:

I have a registration form on a site I have built where people register for a portal. In two PCs in my office, where I have connected an id card reader, I want people to be able to to fill the registration form by swiping their ID card in the reader. So, I need a javascript on the page, that will get the data from the reader, divide it into specific parts and put each of them into the appropriate text field in the registration form. For security purposes, I don't want to have this javascript in the page, and I can't have two different registration pages, so I just need that in the two computers of my office, this script to be injected into the source code before the page renders. Is this possible with some kind of Google Chrome extensions or something else?

Thank you!

Comment: you're not really making much sence, but if your question is : can I run Javascript that the client can't acces? the answer is No.

Comment: You can use Grease Monkey for Firefox and it seems that google chrome have user scripts built in.

Comment: No, I'm asking if I can put a piece of javascript into a page, from my PC. It's something malware do all the time, I just need to do it for good purposes, on my own PC.

Comment: Thank you jcubic, I'm going to check that right away.

Comment: http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/user-scripts

Answer (score 0):

If you have physical access to the machines, you can write a **[browser extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted)** to do it on just those two computers.

Other than that, there's nothing you can do server-side to identify those machines specifically in a secure fashion.